# How to join and get data with multiple table but the same structure?

Tags: mysql, sql

Join multiple table and get data in one line.

tbl_2012-08 (structure)

```
id | data_log | data_name 

1  | 0001     | first
2  | 0002     | second
```

tbl_2012-09 (structure)

```
id | data_log | data_name 

1  | 0003     | third
```

Output:

```
data_log
0001
0002
0003
```

How could I join this 2 table so that I can extract data at once.
any case would help
like:
create another table or something

Comment: `UNION` or `UNION ALL`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you have separate tables for each month but you should be able to use a `UNION` query to return the data from both tables:

```
select id, data_log, data_name
from `tbl_2012-08`
union all
select id, data_log, data_name
from `tbl_2012-09`
```

I used a `UNION ALL` to return all rows from both tables which will include duplicates (if any).  You cannot `JOIN` the tables unless you have some common value in both tables and if you have separate tables for each month then I would guess that you don't have a common value in both tables.

As side note,  I might include include a column so you can easily identify what table the data is coming from:

```
select id, data_log, data_name, '2012-08' mth
from `tbl_2012-08`
union all
select id, data_log, data_name, '2012-09' mth
from `tbl_2012-09`
```

My suggestion would be to look at changing this data structure, having a separate table for each month will get very cumbersome to manage.

If you want to just return the `data_log`, then you just use:

```
select data_log
from `tbl_2012-08`
union all
select data_log
from `tbl_2012-09`
```

Comment: I separate this table cause its a log. and holds large amount of data every month.

Comment: @user2324375 The problem is when you get to 5 years, you will have a ridiculous amount of tables to manage.  Tables are able to store a lot of data, creating extra tables is bad practice IMO.

Comment: so what are you suggesting?
create only one table and get billions of data on it?

Comment: @user2324375 I am not going to argue the ins and outs of database design but the route you are going with creating separate tables for each month is bad practice.  In your situation if you needed to return a full year of data you will have to UNION 12 tables instead of just using a WHERE filter with a date.

Comment: @user2324375 Sure. When properly indexed and using the right queries, databases can handle lots of data quite efficiently. Creating an extra table each month will be hard to manage (new table = queries need to be updated). A fixed amount of tables will be a lot easier to handle in the long run. If you only actively use the data from the last X months you could always opt for an 'ArchivedLog' table and a 'Log' table.

Answer (score 0):

You should uses  [UNION ALL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

```
SELECT id, data_log, data_name
FROM `tbl_2012-08`
UNION ALL
SELECT id, data_log, data_name
FROM`tbl_2012-09`
```

In this case the Union will join the result from one select statement with the other to make one table. Its important to note that both select statements must return the same number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `union all`.  But, you should also include a column identifying where the data came from.  In this case, I assume it is the date:

```
SELECT '2012-08' as YYYYMM, id, data_log, data_name
FROM `tbl_2012-08`
UNION ALL
SELECT '2012-09' as YYYYMM, id, data_log, data_name
FROM`tbl_2012-09`;
```

In addition, if you want the `id` to be unique after bringing them together, then this will work:

```
select YYYYMM, (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, id as old_id, data_log, data_name
from ((SELECT '2012-08' as YYYYMM, id, data_log, data_name
       FROM `tbl_2012-08`
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT '2012-09' as YYYYMM, id, data_log, data_name
       FROM`tbl_2012-09`
      )
     ) t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) const;
```

You can also create another table by doing:

```
create table new_table as
    <either of the queries above>
```